# App crashes at .apk

Tags: android

The app I created is running great on emulator or on my device when i connect the cable, but when I create an .apk file (I am sending it to myself )and I try to run it on my device in crashes.

In the past it worked in other apps I created but on that case it wont. 
 I am using the `.android/debug.keystore` with its default key(`android`). I've tried to create a new keystore aswell but the app still crashes when I run the apk.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of error - has any clue how to fix it?

Edit:

the bugSense tells me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xx.xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.CommonUtilities
at xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.onTabChanged(Tabs.java:617) 
at xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.initialiseTabHost(Tabs.java:544)
at xx.xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.onCreate(Tabs.java:90)
```

Comment: Post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: I can not have a logcat since it is an apk file that I am sending via email to myself

Comment: so how does it crash? Howerer it is complity irrelevant the keystore you used to sign your app. It is not the cause of the crash

Comment: @ManosK There's still a log cat.  Once you install the apk and run it - and the app crashed - connect the phone to the computer again and run `adb -d logcat` - it will show you the log.

Comment: Yes I saw it already thank you, but yet it shows me the same error with bugSense

Answer (score 2):

there're two options to your NoClassDefFoundError

1. ProGuard is shrinking the file and removing/stripping out/re-compressing libraries that your app needs to work.
2. Your build path is not properly configured and a library you use is not being packed into the .apk

**edit:**

where's CommonUtilities being defined? External library?

Comment: It is defined inside the main package of the application

Comment: are you using ProGuard? It's likely then that for some reason ProGuard thinks that you're not using this class and stripping it out of the final .apk. Are you accessing this class by reflections or directly?

Comment: No I am not using the proguard, since I have not enabled the settings

Comment: what's the full package path for this xx.xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.CommonUtilities ? Is something from the Android framework? From the support library? or you created yourself and it's inside your app?

Comment: The full package path is something I created myself and it is inside my app

Comment: well... good luck then. I can't think on any other reason for your problem.

Comment: My problem is still not solved from where i will get thia option

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I was doing the export of the apk from right click->export!
You must do that kind of export on the final product when it is ready for release.

The right way to export when your app is still on development is right click on the project->Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package.

Many thanks to all for your help learned new things on android from that question.

Comment: `project->Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package` that's always how you export an android project. If you want to export it during development you can export the unsigned app. But you must always export an Android project through the Android Tools menu.